# Definition of inverse matrix and matrix of minors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Explain what it means that a matrix $A$ is invertible. Define the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$.

I said:

A matrix $A$ is invertible if $\det(A) \neq 0$. The inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ is a matrix such that $A^{-1} \cdot A = A \cdot A^{-1} = I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Would you agree with this?

> Define the Minor matrix $M_{ij}$ for a square matrix $||a_{ij}||_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$.

I said that the Minor matrix corresponding to element $i,j$ is the matrix you get after cancelling out row $i$ and column $j$. However my friend said that after you cancel out the row and column and then take the determinant, you end up with the minor matrix.

Which definition is correct?

Comment: If you cancel row $i$ and coulmn $j$ and take the determinant you get the minor $M_{i,j}$. But this is just a number. The matrix you are looking for is probably the adjugate matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Answer (score 2):

> In linear algebra, a minor of a matrix A is the determinant of some smaller square matrix, cut down from A by removing one or more of its rows or columns.

From [Minor (linear algebra)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28matrix%29).

So your friend is right. The minor of a matrix is a number, not a matrix.

EDIT : You're also right about the inverse of a matrix